# When wavelet estimates fail?

Tags: st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis, signal-analysis

I am interested in some models studied in non-parametric estimation, more precisely the Gaussian white noise model,

$$dX_{t_{1},...,t_{d}}=f(t_{1},...,t_{d})dt_{1}...dt_{d}+\theta dW_{t_{1},...,t_{d}}$$

with :

- $W$ the noise, a $d-$parameters Wiener field, i.e. a Gaussian separable real-valued field on $[0,1]^{d}$ with zero mean and covariance function :
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left[W(t) W(s)\right]=\prod_{i=1}^d t_i \wedge s_i
  $$
- $f$ the signal, a real-valued function over $[0,1]^{d}$
- $\theta\geq0$ the level of noise

In this context, estimating $f$ is a well-studied task, an optimal method (in the minimax sense), that is nice also from a numerical point of view, is using a wavelet bases and estimates the associated wavelet coefficients. But, at least from what I know (mostly contained in A. Tsybakov book : https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b13794), theoretical guarantees on the convergence of these kinds of methods require some uniform regularity assumptions, classes of signals that are considered are usually Hölder, Sobolev or Besov functions. I wonder how wavelet estimates perform outside these classes (existing result for more irregular signals ?). Especially, I am looking for examples of function classes where wavelet estimates gives poor results theoretically or numerically (especially in low dimension).

Also, from a more applied perspective, do datasets of such signals are available somewhere ?